# Enable DocuSign Connect feature on user's account via API

Tags: docusignapi

As we were working in sandbox environment - we didn't realise that "DocuSign Connect" feature is disabled by default on live accounts.

We rely on this feauture and we would like to enable it on user's account once the user authenticates in DocuSign on our side.

I'm able to retrieve the status of this feature by a GET request to /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}
However it seems that there are no endpoints to update the Account information or to enable DocuSign Connect feature.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like I was incorrect. However, Connect is not enabled by default on all production accounts, there is a cost associated with it.

Comment: Thank you. How do you know this?
I've looked up DocuSign pricing table and it shows that features like "Custom API integrations" and "Salesforce/CRM connectors" are only available with enterprise license. Which kind of confirms your words
It looks like we are going to do polling for the users that don't have connect enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, connect is only available for DocuSign enterprise accounts.

EventNotification (Connect notifications requested on a per-envelope basis) is included with all api-enabled accounts.